# Random Name Generator providing same name to multiple objects

Tags: c#, string, random

I'm working on a hobby project creating a 'World Generator.' I am trying to populate my world with lots of 'Human' objects which each get a randomly generated name. I have a class NameGenerator that has a function generateName which each time it is called should generate a random name. In my world, I am running a 'day' function every second that adds 100 people to the person list. For some reason when this is run, a lot of the human objects get the same name generated although they should have different names.

---

Here is my code:

**mainGui.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JamiesWorldGenerator
{
    public partial class WorldGeneratorForm : Form
    {
        World world = null;

        public WorldGeneratorForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void runButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (runButton.Text == "Run")
            {
                if (world == null) world = new World(this, 1000);
                world.run();

                runButton.Text = "Stop";
                statusLabel.Text = "Status: Active";
            }
            else if (runButton.Text == "Stop")
            {
                world.pause();

                runButton.Text = "Run";
                statusLabel.Text = "Status: Inactive";
            }
        }

        public void updateTimeElapsed(int i)
        {
            this.daysElapsedLabel.Text = "Days Elapsed: " + i;
        }

        public void updatePersonList(List<Human> list)
        {
            foreach (Human h in list) this.peopleList.Items.Add(h);
            peopleList.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        }
    }
}
```

**mainGui.designer.cs**

```
namespace JamiesWorldGenerator
{
    partial class WorldGeneratorForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.populationLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.runButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.statusLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.countriesList = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.peopleList = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.panel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.worldNews = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.daysElapsedLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel3.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // populationLabel
            // 
            this.populationLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.populationLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 9);
            this.populationLabel.Name = "populationLabel";
            this.populationLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 13);
            this.populationLabel.TabIndex = 0;
            this.populationLabel.Text = "World Population: ";
            // 
            // runButton
            // 
            this.runButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 320);
            this.runButton.Name = "runButton";
            this.runButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.runButton.TabIndex = 1;
            this.runButton.Text = "Run";
            this.runButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.runButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.runButton_Click);
            // 
            // statusLabel
            // 
            this.statusLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.statusLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 325);
            this.statusLabel.Name = "statusLabel";
            this.statusLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81, 13);
            this.statusLabel.TabIndex = 2;
            this.statusLabel.Text = "Status: Inactive";
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.countriesList);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 25);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 187);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // countriesList
            // 
            this.countriesList.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.countriesList.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.countriesList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.countriesList.Name = "countriesList";
            this.countriesList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 187);
            this.countriesList.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.peopleList);
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(215, 25);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 187);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // peopleList
            // 
            this.peopleList.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.peopleList.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.peopleList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.peopleList.Name = "peopleList";
            this.peopleList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(197, 187);
            this.peopleList.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // panel3
            // 
            this.panel3.Controls.Add(this.worldNews);
            this.panel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 219);
            this.panel3.Name = "panel3";
            this.panel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 95);
            this.panel3.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // worldNews
            // 
            this.worldNews.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.worldNews.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.worldNews.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.worldNews.Name = "worldNews";
            this.worldNews.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 95);
            this.worldNews.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(336, 320);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 6;
            this.button1.Text = "Load World";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(255, 320);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 7;
            this.button2.Text = "Save World";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // daysElapsedLabel
            // 
            this.daysElapsedLabel.AutoSize = true;
            this.daysElapsedLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(212, 9);
            this.daysElapsedLabel.Name = "daysElapsedLabel";
            this.daysElapsedLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 13);
            this.daysElapsedLabel.TabIndex = 8;
            this.daysElapsedLabel.Text = "Days Elapsed: 0";
            // 
            // WorldGeneratorForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(423, 351);
            this.Controls.Add(this.daysElapsedLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.statusLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.runButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.populationLabel);
            this.Name = "WorldGeneratorForm";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Jamie\'s World Generator";
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label populationLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button runButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label statusLabel;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox countriesList;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox peopleList;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox worldNews;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label daysElapsedLabel;
    }
}
```

**World.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JamiesWorldGenerator
{
    public class World
    {
        private delegate void updateForm();

        WorldGeneratorForm gui = null;

        List<Country> worldCountries = new List<Country>();
        List<Human> worldHumans = new List<Human>();

        List<Human> newWorldHumans;

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        int daysElapsed = 0;

        public World(WorldGeneratorForm mainGui, int dayDelay)
        {
            gui = mainGui;

            timer.Interval = dayDelay;
            timer.Elapsed += day;
        }

        private void day(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newWorldHumans = new List<Human>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                NameGenerator nameGen = new NameGenerator();
                Human h = new Human(nameGen.generateName(4, 8), nameGen.generateName(4, 12));
                worldHumans.Add(h);
                newWorldHumans.Add(h);

            }

            daysElapsed++;
            Delegate updateDays = new updateForm(updateDayElapsed);
            Delegate updatePersonList = new updateForm(updateWorldPopulationList);
            gui.Invoke(updateDays);
            gui.Invoke(updatePersonList);
        }

        public void run()
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void pause()
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void updateDayElapsed()
        {
            gui.updateTimeElapsed(daysElapsed);
        }

        private void updateWorldPopulationList()
        {
            gui.updatePersonList(newWorldHumans);
        }
    }
}
```

**Human.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Globalization;

namespace JamiesWorldGenerator
{
    public class Human
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public Human(string fname, string lname)
        {
            FirstName = capitaliseFirst(fname);
            LastName = capitaliseFirst(lname);
            FullName = FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }

        string capitaliseFirst(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length == 0) return "";
            char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
            chars[0] = Char.ToUpperInvariant(chars[0]);
            return new string(chars);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace JamiesWorldGenerator
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new WorldGeneratorForm());
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT - NameGenerator.cs** sorry I thought I posted it too (silly me)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JamiesWorldGenerator
{
    class NameGenerator
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        public string generateName(int minLength, int maxLength)
        {
            string chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            string consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxzw";
            string vowels = "aeiouy";

            int length = random.Next(minLength, maxLength);
            string name = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (name != "")
                {
                    if (endsWithTwoConsonants(name)) name = name + vowels[random.Next(vowels.Length)];
                    else if (endsWithTwoVowels(name)) name = name + consonants[random.Next(consonants.Length)];
                    else name = name + chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
                }
                else name = name + chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }

            return name;
        }

        bool endsWithTwoConsonants(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length < 2) return false;
            string substring = s.Substring(s.Length - 2);
            for(int i = 0; i < substring.Length; i++)
            {
                if (isVowel(substring[i])) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        bool endsWithTwoVowels(string s)
        {
            string[] suffixes = {"aa", "ae", "ai", "ao", "au", "ea", "ee", "ei", "eo", "eu", "ia", "ie", "ii", "io", "iu"
                                ,"oa", "oe", "oi", "oo", "ou", "ua", "ue", "ui", "uo", "uu"};
            for(int i = 0; i < suffixes.Length; i++)
            {
                if (s.EndsWith(suffixes[i])) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        bool isVowel(char c)
        {
            string vowels = "aeiouy";
            if (vowels.Contains(c))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        bool isConsonant(char c)
        {
            string consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvxzw";
            if (consonants.Contains(c))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreaciated

Comment: I guess the problem is the seed of the random generator.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the `NameGenerator` - the one piece of code you've chosen not to share with us, it would seem.

Comment: Please provide the Class `NameGenerator` or at least the method `generateName(int x, int y)`

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]. None of the code you've shown is relevant, and the relevant code is missing. Isolate the problematic code, preferably into a new project, and post that, but not after doing your own research. My guess is that you use `new Random()` in a loop.

Comment: @CodeCaster *but not after doing your own research*, I guess you meant *but not **before** doing your own research*

Comment: @Rafalon sorry, still early.

Comment: Sorry everyone I thought I posted the namegenerator too. Mistakes were made

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll supose placing the NameGenerator nameGen = new NameGenerator(); statement in the day function of World outsite the for loop will solve you're problem.

```
NameGenerator nameGen = new NameGenerator();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   Human h = new Human(nameGen.generateName(4, 8), nameGen.generateName(4, 12));
   worldHumans.Add(h);
   newWorldHumans.Add(h);
}
```

Comment: Yes this one worked. Why does placing it outside the loop make a difference?

Comment: @JamieWalker - because when you call `new Random()` without supplying a seed, it's seeded based on the current datetime value - which takes *ages* to change from the perspective of a modern CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Make the NameGenerator to have singleton Random with initial seed, so everytime you instantiate NameGenerator and generate the name, it would always be different.

```
class NameGenerator
{
    private static readonly Random staticRandom = new Random();
    private Random random {get;set;}

    public NameGenerator()
    {
        random = staticRandom;
    }

...
```